# Why will it not let me take a picture using the Camera Controller?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera

I am trying to create an application using a full-screen camera. The live camera feed works as well as button feedback. It seems that there is a problem at the `_controller.takePicture(path)` line as the "IS INITIALIZED" print statement returns true. I put the path, path provider, and camera dependencies in pubspec.yaml.

Initialization of CameraController

```
cameras = await availableCameras();
    var frontCamera = cameras.first;

    _controller = CameraController(frontCamera, ResolutionPreset.high);
    try {
      await _controller.initialize();
    } catch (e) {
    }
    print('Controller Is Init:' + _controller.value.isInitialized.toString());
    displayPreview();
```

```
child: GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                  child:Container(
                  child: Icon(Icons.camera,color: Colors.white,size: 60,)),
                  onTap: () async {
                    print('IS INITIALIZED'+_controller.value.isInitialized.toString());
                    try {
                      await _controller.takePicture(path);
                    }
                    catch(e){
                      print('E:'+e);
                    }
```

Error:

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:283)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:227)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at io.flutter.plugins.camera.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:77)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:230)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:664)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera(28109):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
E/flutter (28109): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'CameraException' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (28109): #0      _VisualPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:ourearth2020/screens/VisualPage.dart:209:36)
E/flutter (28109): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28109): #1      _VisualPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:ourearth2020/screens/VisualPage.dart)
E/flutter (28109): #2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
E/flutter (28109): #3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
E/flutter (28109): #4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (28109): #5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:219:7)
E/flutter (28109): #6      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:477:9)
E/flutter (28109): #7      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:78:12)
E/flutter (28109): #8      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:124:9)
E/flutter (28109): #9      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (28109): #10     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:18)
E/flutter (28109): #11     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:108:7)
E/flutter (28109): #12     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:220:19)
E/flutter (28109): #13     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter (28109): #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
E/flutter (28109): #15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
E/flutter (28109): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (28109): #17     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (28109): #18     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (28109): #19     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (28109): #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:10)
E/flutter (28109): #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:192:5)
```

Comment: Also, instead of saving the path can I just store it in a file and then just display that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the `path` you provide as a parameter is not a `String` but a `CameraException`.

To create a path, you can do that (requires [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)) :

```
final path = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path + '${DateTime.now()}.png';
```